# Find the diameter of a circle subtended by an angle

Tags: trigonometry, circles, area, arc-length

The question doesn't state whether its subtended at the center or circumference, but I not sure if it matters

The sector a circle subtended by an angle of $22.5$ degrees has an area of $\frac{9\pi}{4}$ squared meters.
I have never done one of these problems before but after searching the internet I found the formula
$$s=r\theta$$

though this is the formula for the arc length and I'm not sure if you can find the diameter from this formula.

Comment: Note $22.5=360/16$

Comment: I have never encountered a problem like this, could I get one more hint?

Comment: The area of a circular sector is the circle's area times the ratio of the angle and $360^o$

Comment: So the equation should be $\frac{9\pi}{4}=Area * \frac{360}{16}$?

Comment: $\frac{9\pi}4=Area\; of circle \times \frac {22.5}{360}$

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally got the answer

Comment: Good.  The formula for area of a sector makes sense in that it's proportional to the area of the circle and the angle of the sector, and when the angle is $360^o$ the area of the sector is equal to the area of the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of a circular sector is the circle's area times the ratio of the angle and $360^o$.

In this case, that ratio is $22.5^o/360^o=1/16$.

Therefore the area of the circle is $16\times\dfrac{9\pi}4 $m$^2 = 36\pi$ m$^2.$

The area of a circle is $\pi r^2$, so in this case $r^2=36$ m$^2,$ so $r=6$ m.

The diameter is twice the radius:  $d=2r=2\times6 $ m $ =12$ m.

[image]